# List of dictionaries set comprehension calculation

Tags: python-3.x, list, datetime, dictionary

My data structure is a list of dicts. I would like to run a function over the values of certain keys, and then output only a certain number of dictionaries as the result.

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse

today = '05/17/18'
adict = [{'taskid':1,'desc':'task1','complexity':5,'dl':'05/28/18'},{'taskid':2,'desc':'task2','complexity':3,'dl':'05/20/18'},
         {'taskid':3,'desc':'task3','complexity':1,'dl':'05/25/18'}]

def conv_tm(t):
    return datetime.strptime(t,'%m/%d/%y')

def days(obj):
    day = conv_tm(today)
    dl = conv_tm(obj)
    dur = (dl-day).days
    if dur <0:
        dur = 1
    return dur
```

I found the easiest way to process the dates for the 'dl' key was to run this dict comprehension:

```
vals = [days(i['dl']) for i in adict]

#this also worked, but I didn't like it as much
vals = list(map(lambda x: days(x['dl']), adict))
```

Now, I need to do 2 things: 1) zip this list back up to the 'dl' key, and 2)return or print a (random) set of 2 dicts w/o altering the origianl dict, perhaps like so:

```
{'taskid':1,'desc':task1,'dl':8,'complexity':5}
{'taskid':3,'desc':task3,'dl':8,'complexity':1}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could produce the new dicts directly like this:

```
new_dicts = [{**d, 'dl': days(d['dl'])} for d in adict]
```

If you need vals separately, you can use it to do this as well:

```
new_dicts = [{**d, 'dl': v} for d, v in zip(adict, vals)]
```

Comment: That's a very simple way to do it! Didn't know you could zip a dictionary like that - very useful, thanks